# S3 Transfer Acceleration Semantics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rather simple question which I cannot find an explicit answer to, but anyone using the subject should be able to answer.

Does [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) follow an eventual model i.e. clients upload to a CF edge location, get the response back and then the data is eventually moved to a bucket OR is the performance (speed) gain is simply because of the AWS internal network usage and upon the request completion the data is always 100% IN the S3 bucket?

If it's the former is there any SLA regarding how fast this eventual process is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 Transfer Acceleration uses CloudFront and CloudFront doesn't cache POST/PUT request which means the data gets uploaded to the S3 at the same time. CloudFront doesn't buffer it, it simply saves your RTT (round trip time) by letting you connect to the nearest edge location compare to when you connect to S3 endpoint situated far from you.

And, since transfer between CloudFront and S3 is in AWS Network, it should be faster.

(buffer in the sense you can consider Acceleration endpoint as proxy).

Answer (score 1):

S3 Transfer Acceleration uses portions of the CloudFront *infrastructure* to provide low-latency, performance-optimized connectivity from browser to edge to bucket.

It does not use any storage or caching components of CloudFront.

The acceleration is only TLS and transport (buffer and routing) related; all HTTP interactions are ultimately end-to-end with the actual S3 bucket, with CloudFront edge servers providing termination for the browser-facing TLS session and a reverse-proxy function.

Nothing stored outside the bucket, so S3's standard consistency model applies.